# How can I store the values chosen by the user into n DropDown rendered by a SharePoint Web Part?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I am pretty new in **.NET* and **SharePoint** and I have the following problem.

I am developing a **Web Part** (into Share Point 2013) that retrieve n SharePoint list (the number of these lists is variable, it is not a fixed number) and use the content of these lists to render n **DropDown** (the content of these drop down is the content of the related SharePoint list).

So basically into the **Page_Load()** method of my Web Part I have something like this (it works):

```
else if (mode != null && mode.Equals("scelta_campi_facoltativi_etichetta"))
{

    SPList listaCampiOpzionaliEtichetta = contextWeb.Lists["ListaCampiOpzionaliEtichetta"];

    String tipoDocumentiInternalName = listaCampiOpzionaliEtichetta.Fields["TipoDocumento"].InternalName;
    Clausola c = null;

    if (tipoDoc.Equals("docEntrata"))
    { 
        c = new Clausola(Clausola.condizione.Eq, Clausola.tipoCampo.Choice, Clausola.CondizioneExtra.no, "Entrata", tipoDocumentiInternalName);
    }
    else if(tipoDoc.Equals("docUscita"))
    {
        c = new Clausola(Clausola.condizione.Eq, Clausola.tipoCampo.Choice, Clausola.CondizioneExtra.no, "Uscita", tipoDocumentiInternalName);
    }

    string q = Query.creaQueryWhere(c.query);
    SPQuery queryQ = new SPQuery();
    queryQ.Query = q;

    SPListItemCollection etichetteCollection = listaCampiOpzionaliEtichetta.GetItems(queryQ);

    Table table = new Table();
    table.CellPadding = 2;
    table.CellSpacing = 2;
    table.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

    foreach (SPListItem item in etichetteCollection)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("etichetta: " + item["NomeLista"] + " URL sito: " + item["UrlSito"]);

        SPSite sitoEtichettaCorrente = new SPSite(item["UrlSito"].ToString());  // Top level website of the site collection
        SPWeb currentWebSite = sitoEtichettaCorrente.OpenWeb();

        //SPList eitchettaCorrenteList =  currentWebSite.GetList(item["NomeLista"].ToString());

        SPList eitchettaCorrenteList = currentWebSite.Lists[item["NomeLista"].ToString()];

        String nomeColonna = item["NomeColonna"].ToString();
        String codice = item["Codice"].ToString();

        TableRow rigaCorrente = new TableRow();

        TableCell cell1Corrente = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell2Corrente = new TableCell();

        cell1Corrente.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl((String)item["NomeLista"]));

        DropDownList dropDownnEtichetta = new DropDownList();
        for (int i = 0; i < eitchettaCorrenteList.Items.Count; i++)
        {

            dropDownnEtichetta.CssClass = "chosen-select";
            dropDownnEtichetta.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
            dropDownnEtichetta.ID = (String)item["NomeLista"];

            string valoreDaMostrareInternalName = eitchettaCorrenteList.Fields[nomeColonna].InternalName;
            string valoreDaStampareInternalName = eitchettaCorrenteList.Fields[codice].InternalName;

            string valoreDaMostrare = eitchettaCorrenteList.Items[i].GetFormattedValue(valoreDaMostrareInternalName);
            string valoreDaStampare = eitchettaCorrenteList.Items[i].GetFormattedValue(valoreDaStampareInternalName);

            dropDownnEtichetta.Items.Add(new ListItem(valoreDaMostrare, valoreDaStampare));

            cell2Corrente.Controls.Add(dropDownnEtichetta);

            rigaCorrente.Controls.Add(cell1Corrente);
            rigaCorrente.Controls.Add(cell2Corrente);


        }

        table.Controls.Add(rigaCorrente);

    }
    sceltaCampiEtichettaPanel.Controls.Add(table);

    HtmlGenericControl buttondiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

    Button bottoneConfermaCampiFacoltativiEtichetta = new Button();
    bottoneConfermaCampiFacoltativiEtichetta.Text = "Conferma";
    bottoneConfermaCampiFacoltativiEtichetta.CssClass = "shiny-blue";
    //bottoneConfermaCampiFacoltativiEtichetta.OnClientClick = "return validatePwd();";
    //bottoneConfermaCampiFacoltativiEtichetta.Click += ButtonSalva_Click;

    buttondiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
    buttondiv.Controls.Add(bottoneConfermaCampiFacoltativiEtichetta);

    sceltaCampiEtichettaPanel.Controls.Add(buttondiv);
}
```

As you can see I am retrieving a list of SharePoint lists. I iterate on each list and I populate the contend of the rendered DropDown with the content of the related current list.

Now my problem is: the user can select a value from these **DropDown**. I want to store (probably at class level) the values chosen by the user into these dropdown.

What could be a smart strategy to implement this task?

Comment: so next time web part loads, you want to show the user the value they previously chose?

Comment: @Tany3450 yes, exactly

Comment: Since it will be different for each user, I would create a new user profile property and store it there. Then you can fetch it for the current user on the page load.